# Using eventsByPersistenceId for getting the source of events in reverse order

Tags: scala, akka, event-sourcing, akka-stream, akka-persistence

I have a `PersistentActor` that `persist`s events and I would like to read them in reverse order. More specifically, I would like to get a `Source` for the events that emits the events in reversed order. This is useful for answering queries about the last N events that happened for that `PersistentActor`. What is the right approach for this problem? This information should be kept cached in the view or there is a way that I can lazily query about the events in reverse order?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**If** your ultimate goal is "answering queries about the last N events" then you can write a scaning Flow using a [circular buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304695/scala-collections-circular-buffer/34817892#34817892):

```
import scala.collection.immutable

type CircularBuffer[T] = immutable.Vector[T]

def emptyCircularBuffer[T] : CircularBuffer[T] = immutable.Vector.empty[T]

def addToCircularBuffer[T](maxSize : Int)(buffer : CircularBuffer[T], item : T) : CircularBuffer[T]  =
  if(maxSize > 0)
    buffer.drop(buffer.size - maxSize + 1) :+ item
  else 
    buffer

import akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow

def circularBufferFlow[T](N : Int) = 
  Flow[T].scan(emptyCircleBuffer[T])(addToCircleBuffer[T](N))
```

This Flow will hold between 0 and N elements, and emits a new Buffer with each update:

```
Source(1 to 10).via(circularBufferFlow[Int](3))
               .runWith(Sink.foreach(println))

//Vector()
//Vector(1)
//Vector(1, 2)
//Vector(1, 2, 3)
//Vector(2, 3, 4)
//Vector(3, 4, 5)
//...
```

To get the very last buffer exclusively you can use `Sink.last` to materialize the entire flow into a `Future`.

**If**, however, your goal is truly to reverse a Stream then I would consider this  unwise since a Stream could potentially go on for infinite which would result in your cache eventually consuming all of the JVM's memory and crashing the application.